SDK issue com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1
When I try to publish my application on the play store, I receive the following warning.

com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1 Update your Maven dependency to a version compatible with Android 14. Your existing com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1 library is not compatible with targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which includes the backwards incompatible broadcast receiver change. As a reminder, starting from August 31, 2024, all new app versions on Google Play must target Android 14. Update the library dependency to the latest version to prevent applications from crashing.

I couldn't solve the error
